# Having trouble deserializing XML with unwrapped collection

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

What is the right way to deserialize the following XML using C#?

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gCal='http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005'>
    <id>http://www.google.com/cal...</id>
    <subtitle type='text'>RockPointe Events (1)</subtitle>
    <entry>
        <id>http://www.google.com/cal...</id>
        <published>2011-07-07T21:43:44.000Z</published>
        <updated>2011-07-07T21:48:31.000Z</updated>
        <title type='html'>Event 1</title>
        <summary type='html'>Event 1 Summary</summary>
        <content type='html'>Event 1 Content</content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>http://www.google.com/cal...</id>
        <published>2011-07-07T21:43:44.000Z</published>
        <updated>2011-07-07T21:48:31.000Z</updated>
        <title type='html'>Event 2</title>
        <summary type='html'>Event 2 Summary</summary>
        <content type='html'>Event 2 Content</content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Here's my current POCO

```cs
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public class Feed
    {
        [XmlElement("subtitle")]
        public string Subtitle { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("entry")]
        public m_Entry[] Entry { get; set; }

        [XmlType(Namespace = "")]
        public class m_Entry
        {
            [XmlElement("title")]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("summary")]
            public string Summary { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("content")]
            public string Content { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("published")]
            public DateTime Published { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("updated")]
            public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

When I run it through my `Deserialize` method, I get `Title` and `Subtitle` as expected. The problem is with `entry`. I get two entries represented, but everything is null.

[image: null entry]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it appears it was as easy as removing the `XmlType` attribute from the Entry Class

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class Feed
{
    [XmlElement("subtitle")]
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("entry")]
    public Entry[] Entries { get; set; }

    public class Entry
    {
        [XmlElement("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("summary")]
        public string Summary { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("published")]
        public DateTime Published { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("updated")]
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is that you're deserializing the `entry` array as a single element rather than an array. Perhaps you should consider changing the decorators to something along the lines of:

```
[XmlArray("feed")]
[XmlArrayItem("entry", typeof(m_Entry))]
public m_Entry[] entry { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but instead of an array of `null` entry properties (what I have above), yours just returns an `entry` object as `null`